# React Native global variable apikey

Tags: api, reactjs, native

My aplication has a login and it gets from the api a apikey when the user logged in that saves in the this.state. I need to be able to acces the apikey from every screen of the app. How can i do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [**AsyncStorage**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)

> AsyncStorage is a simple, asynchronous, persistent, key-value
>   storage system that is global to the app. It should be used instead of
>   LocalStorage.